# Text in NavBar React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm find a problem about a text in the navBar.

I use router-flux.

My problem is that I have insert the Logout at the right in the navBar, but I would show this button only at a category of user.

So If your role is "user1": You can logout.

If your role is "user2": You can't logout and you shouldn't see the "logout" text.

This is the code that I use to show the logout button:

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  static redirectLogout() {
    Alert.alert("Logout", "Logout effettuato con successo");
    Actions.authentication();
  }
  static logout() {
    Utente.clearUtenteLoggato();
    App.redirectLogout();
  }
    <Scene
                key="homepageutente"
                component={HomepageUtente}
                type="reset"
                leftTitle="Home"
                leftButtonTextStyle={{color: "#ffffff"}}
                onLeft={() => Actions.authentication()}
                rightButtonTextStyle={{color: "#ffffff"}}
                rightTitle="Logout"
                onRight={() => App.logout()}
                navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#64c7c0" }}
              />
```

Do you know how can I do? If more information is needed, I will provide it immediately. Thank you very much

EDIT:
This is the structure of the App:

First page:

**Authentication**:
(you can go to)
  --> **LoginConsumer**

--> **LoginPlus**

I Use a White page that is load after click on one button to check if you are logged in and what kind of user you are.

Starting.js

```
class Starting extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Utente.getUtenteLoggato()
      .then(dataUtenteLoggato => {   
        if (dataUtenteLoggato !== null) {
          global.utente = new Utente(JSON.parse(dataUtenteLoggato));
          Actions.homepageutente()({type: 'reset'});
        } else if(Roles == "ROLE_PLUS") { // But this doesn't work :(
          console.log(Roles)
          Actions.loginplus();
        }
        else {
          Actions.loginconsumer()
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
  }
```

So If you are and Role_Plus you can't logout.

Starting.js call the "getUtenteLoggato" from Utente:

```
 static async getUtenteLoggato() {
    try {
      return await AsyncStorage.getItem("@UtenteLoggato");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple ternary condition to determine the state of this by checking on the user1 state:

```
       <Scene
            key="homepageutente"
            component={HomepageUtente}
            type="reset"
            leftTitle="Home"
            leftButtonTextStyle={{color: "#ffffff"}}
            onLeft={() => Actions.authentication()}
            rightButtonTextStyle={{color: "#ffffff"}}
            rightTitle={user === "user1" ? "Logout" : ""}
            onRight={user === "user1" ? () => App.logout() : () => {}}
            navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#64c7c0" }}
            />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The problem is that it can't find the variable User (I have declared all the pages in this router page)

Comment: Maybe post your app's structure and component tree, I can't think of a way to toggle something based on the user without knowing the user state. I'm not familiar with router-flux though maybe I'm missing something!

Comment: Can you post the render method of the Starting component as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you refer at what I add now?

Comment: Maybe the problem should be that the App.js page is the first one to load?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this way of structuring a react app. But the solution is clear, you have to somehow return the state of the user in one of your Actions and save that to the component state object so then you can check in your render method for it.

Comment: But since App.js is the first page that is executed, do I have to retrieve the user information from the database in any way? The problem is that it does not find the Roles attribute that is inside the DB for each user

Comment: Yes, retrieve the role attribute from the db in the App.js, save that to state and then pass that attribute as needed to the components. React also has a static context object, if you rather save it there instead of passing it down as an attribute. Check it out here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html